# Reference for the notion of polyhedra "degenerations"

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, toric-varieties

Let $P$ be a convex polyhedron and let $P(t)$ be a continuous deformation thereof, such that:

a) $P(0)=P$;

b) for all $t\in[0;1)$ the polyhedron $P(t)$ is strongly combinatorially equivalent to $P$ (has the same normal fan).

Let $Q=P(1)$ and call such a $Q$ a *degeneration* of $P$. In other words, if one views the set of polyhedra strongly combinatorially equivalent to $P$ as the interior of the suitable polyhedral cone, then degenerations of $P$ are given by points on that cone's boundary (as well as, formally, the interior points).

Now, it isn't hard to see that $Q$ is a degeneration of $P$ in the above sense iff the normal fan of $P$ refines the normal fan of $Q$.

What would a good reference for this notion be? ("Degeneration" might very well not be the standard terminology.) In particular, I would like the source to prove the equivalence of the above approaches.

Comment: I have certainly heard this phrase "coarsening of the normal fan". Another phrase to look for is "Minkowski summand", e.g. of the Chow polytope in the Gr\"obner polytope. The example I've seen people pursue is "pseudo-Weyl polytopes", degenerations of $hull(W\cdot \lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is a regular dominant weight for a Weyl group $W$. (Those have more degenerations than just $\lambda$ nonregular.)

Comment: I agree with Allen, "coarsening of the normal fan" is commonly used for this. One of the first references is P. McMullen, Representations of polytopes and polyhedral sets. Geometriae Dedicata, 2:83–99, 1973. As a book I'd refer to Ewald, Combinatorial convexity and algebraic geometry. An outline is also given in [our article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.1560) with Fillastre. Note that the set of all combinatorial types for given outer normals is related to the secondary polytope.